# How to validate a string containing a "time" which should be exactly this: 99:99:99.99?

Tags: python, validation, time

I have a string that should follow exactly this format:
**99:99:99.99**
(where 9 is a numeric character 0-9,  ... colons separate the numbers except for the last two digits where a period is before).  Its a subtitle film format actually.

How do I check validity for this in Python ?

I tried something like this, but didn't work:

```
if time.strptime(mystring, "%H:%M:%S.%y"):
   print("Start time good.")
```

Comment: There is no hour 99, no minute 99, or second 99.   You're constraining yourself to what is a reasonable value for `%H` (0-23), `%M` (0-59?), and `%S` (0-60?).

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to implement regular expressions:

```
import re

string1='12:34:56.78'
r = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2}')
if r.match(string1) is not None:
    print(string1)
```

In the code above, the string is compared with the defined format: `\d` represents a Unicode decimal digit character, `{2}` defines the repetition qualifier, and the `:` or `.` separators are defined.

You can learn more about the flags by reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).